# Help with another trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

Trying to create a trigger that will add the "sales line" campaign whenever a lead with the leadsource "sales line" is created. These are always created manually. This does not work and I know it has something to do with the line `if(L.leadsource = 'Sales Line')`, I am just not sure what to do from here. TIA

```
trigger Create_Campaign_SalesLine on Lead (after insert) {

    try {  
        if (Trigger.new.size() == 1) {
            List <CampaignMember> cm = new list<CampaignMember>();

            for(Lead L : Trigger.new) {

                    String cname = L.leadsource;
                    if(L.leadsource = 'Sales Line')

                    List <Campaign> c = [select id, name from Campaign where name = :cname limit 1];

                    if(!c.isEmpty()){
                        CampaignMember cml = new CampaignMember();
                        cml.campaignid = c[0].id;
                        cml.leadid = l.id;
                        cm.add(cml);
                    }
            }
            if(!cm.isEmpty()){
                insert cm;
            }
        }
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
        system.debug ('error: ' + e.getMessage() );
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are using a single = which means assignment, rather than == which is for comparison.

What you are actually doing is setting the value of l.leadsource to 'Sales Line' and then the result of that is not a boolean so the expression fails.

Use this instead

```
if(L.leadsource == 'Sales Line')
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I figured it out. I just removed that line and it worked. Just have to make sure I have no other campaigns named the same as my leadsources! Sweet.

Comment: Doug B has got the reason why removing that line made it work.